# discord.py непонятная ошибка

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я создаю ботов в библиотеке discord.py после обновления библиотеки возникает диссонанс.

при запуске бота возникает вот такая ошибка.

```
Trace (last last call): 
File "G:\бот\arterial mod.py ", line 17, in client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX ) 
Error type: BotBase.init() missing 1 required argument only for keywords: 'intents' [Completed after 4.5 s]
```

Вот сам код, в котором ошибка

```
client = teams.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX )
client.remove_command( 'help' )
```

Вот все библиотеки, которые подключены

```
import discord from discord.ext 
import commands from discord 
import permissions from discord.utils 
import receiving 
import requests from PIL 
import images, ImageFont, ImageDraw 
import I/O from youtube_dl 
import YoutubeDL 
import sqlite3
```

До обновления все работало без проблем по тому же сценарию.

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: а что непонятного в ошибке? Все понятно написано.

Comment: я еще не очень разбираюсь во всех ошибках питона поэтому и спрашиваю

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли добавить обязательный аргумент, intents.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX, intents=discord.Intents.all())
```